# ignore top table row styling

Tags: html, css, styled-components

How do I ignore styling on the top row of my table? I want all rows under the top row to not be red.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const StyledTable = styled.table`
    margin-bottom: 40px;
`;

export const TR = styled.tr`
    background-color: red;
    &:hover {
        background-color: #EAEAEA;
    }
`;
```

Edit: I want to provide additional clarity. I want to change color of my rows on hover. But not do this on the top row, for example:

[image]

Comment: Color the cells instead

Comment: It needs to be the whole row. The aim is to change color of the row on hover but it also does this on the top row too

Answer (score 3):

There're the semantic tag for table head `thead`. You can use it to style first row.

Otherwise you can use pseudo-classes like `:first-child` to style first row

```css
#table1 td, #table2 td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#table1 thead tr {
  background: red;
}

#table2 tr:first-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Using thead tag</h2>

<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Head 1</td>
      <td>Head 2</td>
      <td>Head 3</td>
      <td>Head 4</td>
    <tr/>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
    <tr/>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Using pseudo-classes</h2>

<table id="table2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
      <td>Body cell</td>
    <tr/>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
export const TR = styled.tr`
    background-color: red;
    &:hover {
        background-color: #EAEAEA;
    }
    
    
    &:first-child: {
    //your style for first rows here 
    }
`;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work?

export const TR = styled.tr`
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    &:hover {
        background-color: #EAEAEA;
    }

    &:first-child: {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
`;